# How do you install tensorflow 2 on Mac with anaconda

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

(Beginner)

I want to install tensorflow 2 but can seem to figure out how. I have seen a variety of different methods but am not sure what the best is. How can I install Tensorflow 2 on Mac with anaconda?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
pip3 install -q tensorflow==2.0.0  
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.0.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.0.0
jordan2 ~ % pip3 install tensorflow
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
jordan2 ~ %     conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow

zsh: command not found: conda
jordan2 ~ % pip install tensorflow-gpu

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu
```

Comment: Please can you try ```conda create -n tf-gpu tensorflow-gpu``` ```conda activate tf-gpu
```. For more details kindly refer https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/

Comment: If you're using Conda, then `conda create -n tf-env tensorflow=2` should work. Be careful about mixing pip and Conda.

Comment: for some reason the terminal doesn't recognize Conda. Is this an issue with path, and If so how should I fix it